# Is it possible to speak English only using simpler tenses

Tags: tense

Is it possible to be grammatically correct and describe any situation with use of Simple and Continuous tenses? With no use of Perfect and Perfect Continuous.

Comment: What about the past or the future? Do you never want to talk about what will happen or happened to you??

Comment: @Mari-Lou past, present and future is in every group including indefinite and continuous. I can use Past Indefinite or Future Indefinite, right?

Comment: Oh, so you mean simple past, past continuous, simple present, present continuous, simple future, and simple future continuous. Yeah, you'll be understood.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA that you will be understood. But will you be able to "describe any situation" while remaining grammatically correct? That's less clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is as if you had asked "can you speak English without using the word 'dog'?" It's possible, but eventually you will want to refer to a canine pet and then you are stuck.

Roughly 5% of verbs in English texts have their perfect form.  So this is not a rare or obscure part of grammar.  In many cases it might be possible to rephrase with past tense, but there is often a change in meaning or nuance.

And even if you have succeeded in avoiding perfect tenses, what will you do when someone speaks to you? You need to know and understand the perfect tenses to be able to communicate in English fluently.

Comment: Thanks. But not quite agree about the last paragraph. A person can absolutely understand the other with no being able yet to correctly put the same king of sentence together on his own. I don't mean myself, just wanted to clarify necessity of more complex tenses. I got you, thanks.